# Conditions in list comprehensions. Why is it different when I use 'else'?

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

Code A:

```
numbers = [2, -1, 79, 33, -45]
negative_doubled = [num * 2 for num in numbers if num < 0]
print(negative_doubled) # output is: [-2, -90]
```

Code B:

```
numbers = [2, -1, 79, 33, -45]
doubled = [num * 2 if num < 0 else num * 3 for num in numbers ]
print(doubled) # output is: [6, -2, 237, 99, -90]
```

As you can see the position of the `if` statements are different. In code A, the `if` statement positioned after the for loop statement.

Why don't they write the code like this? I would find it more intuitive.

```
numbers = [2, -1, 79, 33, -45]
negative_doubled = [num * 2 if num < 0 for num in numbers] # SyntaxError
print(negative_doubled)
```

(As you know this placement is a syntax error.)

Is there any case where it could be a problem?

Comment: The reason why I wanna code like that way is, I think, this way can make easier to just delete else statement and run the code without problem.

Comment: I dont' understand your question here. This seems to just be a statement about your opinion about the syntax and language design.

Comment: Actually yes, I am now asking for language design.. I'm thinking the way I said can be more intuitive. So I'm curious and want to find a reason why I can't design language that way.

Comment: It doesn't seem intuitive to me. What goes in that part *should be an expression*. In your syntax, it isn't an expression, it doesn't evaluate to anything.

Comment: Voting to reopen. While this seems like an opinion question, it really stems from a slight misunderstanding of list comprehension, which is excellently explained in @blorgon's answer.

Comment: @joanis true it really helped me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can think of comprehensions in Python as always following this general format:

```py
[expression for iter_var in sequence if some_condition]
```

Where unless an explicit boolean expression is given for `some_condition`, it is assumed true.

The `expression` can be any valid expression in Python, including a ternary expression, which follows the format

```py
x = val if cond else other_val
```

Which is equivalent to

```py
if cond:
    x = val
else:
    x = other_val
```

One comprehension is a simple filter, `[x for x in seq if cond]`. The other is a ternary expression `[x if cond else y for _ in seq]`.

An example of a filtered comprehension:

```py
>>> [x for x in range(10) if x % 2 == 0]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Which is equivalent to

```py
res = []
for x in range(10):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        res.append(x)
```

Here's an example of a ternary comprehension:

```py
>>> [x**2 if x % 2 == 0 else x**3 for x in range(10)]
[0, 1, 4, 27, 16, 125, 36, 343, 64, 729]
```

Which is equivalent to

```py
res = []
for x in range(10):
    res.append(x**2 if x % 2 == 0 else x**3)
```

Here's an example of a combination of the two:

```py
>>> lst = [1, "a", "b", 3, "2", 6]
>>> [x**2 if x % 2 == 0 else x**3 for x in lst if isinstance(x, int)]
[1, 27, 36]
```

Which is equivalent to

```py
res = []
for x in range(10):
    if isinstance(x, int):
        res.append(x**2 if x % 2 == 0 else x**3)
```

### TL;DR

You can think of comprehensions as actually having a single unified structure:

```py
[expression for iter_var in sequence if some_condition]
```

The `expression` can be anything, even a ternary expression which itself contains the `if` and `else` keywords, but in fact has nothing to do with `some_condition` upon which all comprehensions are predicated.

I dunno, I'm tipsy and I don't feel like I'm doing a good job explaining and don't feel like trying anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question, the OP seems to understand how list comprehensions work

Comment: But OP clearly *doesn't* understand how comprehensions work. One uses a ternary assignment expression for the value that gets collected, one uses a filtering statement. This answer attempts to explain the differences.

Comment: Um, no, the OP cleary *does* understand, they are asking why the syntax isn't different, where the predicate would be mixed up with the expression

Comment: Right and I'm trying to explain why the syntax is different by using examples. If OP really wants to get into language theory and Python's grammar specification, then feel free to DM them and jump into the weeds with them.

Comment: Well that's precisely the issue, I don't think you could really answer this *without* getting into something like language theory, issues of certain syntaxes being easier to write parsers for, etc. So, more concretely, nothing above says anything about why you *couldn't* mix the expression and the predicate, so `[x/3 if x!=0 for x in range(3)]`. Ok, you might say, well what about if you *do* want to use a ternary expression? `[x /3 if x > 0 else x / 2x%  if x !=0 for range(3)]`....

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga as @blorgon is explaining, one `if` is a *unary* filter, whereas the other `if` is a *ternary* statement.  The similarity between the two is their spelling.

Comment: @RazzleShazl **i understand that and I think the OP understands that**. Basically the OP is asking, "why must the predicate go to the right of the for-clause and why couldn't if have gone to the left?"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm glad that you understand that.  However, I also believe the OP has a *slight* misunderstanding on the subject.

Comment: Perhaps the answer involves "well, it becomes harder to write a parser when the expression and the predecate can be right next to each other, particularly since the expression can contain `if` in the context of a ternary expression". Or maybe the answer is something like "well, list comprehensions are based on mathematical set builder notation, which usually involves a predicate that is seperated by a colon or a pipe"

Comment: FWIW I've upvoted because this does explain the difference @RazzleShazl mentioned which the OP may be confused about

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes that's a good answer you could have contributed.  It's not the only answer, though.  IMHO if he knew the difference between the two (that they are *different* `if`s) then he wouldn't have asked that question.

Comment: I was trying to understand yall comments and first of all I didn't know there is two different types of `if`s ( if statement and if expression ) and concluded mixing two different `if`s can only confuse the code. Now I might think it's more clear to keep original way. Is there anything I'm missing from here? Also I do admit that I didn't completely understand it but I'm trying to get help and thank you for helping me out.

Comment: @mushroom1324 if you're satisfied by my answer, would you mind marking it as correct by clicking the checkmark?

Comment: @blorgon sure why not

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = [2, -1, 79, 33, -45]
negative_doubled = [num * 2 if num < 0 else num for num in numbers] # SyntaxError
print(negative_doubled)
```

You need to tell your machine what happened if the num >= 0.

Comment: Yeah but  I am asking for language design.. I'm thinking the way I did on the post can be more intuitive and easier to remove else statement and run without problem. So I'm curious and want to find a reason why I can't design language that way.

Comment: @mushroom1324 but what is the relevance of removing the `else` part?

Comment: Because I thought it can give consistency on the code but now I'm trying to understand your comment. I don't know why my syntax doesn't evaluate to anything..

Comment: @mushroom1324 but *what* consistency? The two parts of a list comprehension are the expression and the predicate (well, the third part is the for-claus which defines what the iterable is, but let's ignore that). The expression is only evaluated if the predicate is true. Why would it be more consistent to mix them?